# Dynamic component template rendering dynamic component template seems to be caching component

Tags: broker, dynamic-publishing

I've set up a page where I use a dynamic component template to iterate through a collection and render the components via a java call to globalCpa.getContent which uses the components ID and another dynamic component template. This is for a design that requires dynamic publishing but whilst a content editor can arrange the dynamic elements.

Something strange is happening though. I can publish out the components individually and they appear as they should, but once they're published, it becomes impossible to update them. They unpublish as normal but whenever the components are changed and republished, the original data is still displayed.

Does anyone here have any idea why this might happen?

I'm working with Java/VBscript in Tridion 2011

Thanks,

Kris

Comment: Sounds like your cache is turned on, but not correctly configured. Try turning cache off on your webapp (cd_storage_conf)

Comment: Welcome and thanks for asking on Tridion Stack Exchange, Kris. If it turns out the cache configuration _is_ the problem, then the next step is to set that up properly. The cache should clear on publishing. Another hint that it's a configuration problem is if dynamic component presentations seem to update after a second publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following could be most probable reasons:

- As pointed out correctly above by Nuno - You have CD caching enabled but not configured correctly - You can confirm by "Turning Off" the cache in `cd_storage_conf.xml` in the Deployer module as:
  `<ObjectCache Enabled="false">`
- If turning off the cache still does not work, analyze your code and ensure there is no custom caching has been implemented in the back end code which might be missing a invalidation logic whenever there is an update
- Might sound silly, but ensure to clear the browser caching